# How can i connect to documnet db TLS enabled cluster from databricks spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, aws-documentdb

I want to connect to a document db which has TLS enabled .I could do that from a lambda function with the **rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem** copied with lambda code .I could not do the same with databricks as all the node of cluster should have this file when spark try to connect it always time out.I tried to create the init scripts by following below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/python/import-custom-ca-cert
However it does not help either .Let me know if any one has any clue on this kind of use case .

Note:I can connect to TLS disabled document-db  from same databricks instance .

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing connection time out errors when using an init script to import the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem file on your Spark cluster, try the following steps:

1. Make sure that the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` file is available on the driver node of your Spark cluster. The init script will only be executed on the driver node. You will encounter connection time out errors otherwise.
2. Use the `--conf` option when starting the `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` command to specify the location of the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` file on the driver node. To specify the location of the `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem` file, run:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.mongodb.ssl.caFile=path/to/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

3. Check the Spark cluster logs whether the init script is being executed correctly or if its encountering any errors.

Comment: Thanks but its databricks so its bit differnet how to set those init script .Init script ran actually still time out error is there .I see pem file is being created in driver